# Can Android App be embedded in Web page like old plain java applet?

Tags: android

I know nothing about android platform and can't find answer to this basic question on internet.

Update: OK I cannot embed Android App per se. But can I embed something in Java in Android Webbrowser ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot embed an Android app into a webpage and have it work like the app. However, if you write and organize your code in a modular fashion (lookup Model-View-Controller design patterns), then you should be able to reuse A LOT of your code making it easier to create a new Applet-based interface. It's not a drop-in solution, but it should get you 80% of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

No, for several reasons.

Android apps don't use standard JVM bytecode, so the browser would need a Dalvik plug-in.  As far as I'm aware, such a plug-in does not exist.

Even if you built and packaged the Android app as a .jar rather than a .apk, the standard Java plug-in does not include the Android API classes.

Answer (score 1):

Google Web Toolkit (GWT) code.google.com/webtoolkit/ compiles Java into Javascript, and in my limited experience, works quite well on Android. I needed tight touch screen user interface integration, so I went native, but GWT could work well for many java apps, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

And this is why I love open-source:

[android-dalvik-vm-on-java](http://code.google.com/p/android-dalvik-vm-on-java/)

OK, so it's NOT a 'full' Android/Dalvik implementation, but it would give you a good starter for a possible Java-Applet-based Dalvik plugin solution (you'd need the Android Java frameworks, which, I assume, can be downloaded from http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).

Can't wait to see those apps :-D

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Check these guys out [www.pieceable.com](http://www.pieceable.com)

Fair warning: I'm in no way affiliated with the site or the product, just found this doing similar research