# Only flash lite can be embedded in webpage on Android not java?

Tags: android

As fas as I understand from here [Can Android App be embedded in Web page like old plain java applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664067/can-android-app-be-embedded-in-web-page-like-old-plain-java-applet) I cannot use java in web page for Android. So the left choice is only flash lite can you confirm ? (I exclude javascript/html5 here).

Comment: What? That question has nothing to do with running web pages in the android browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot use java in web page for Android.

Android does not display Java applets in Web pages.

> So the left choice is only flash lite can you confirm ?

Android 2.2+ supports full Flash 10.1, but users have to install the Player from the Android Market. Flash Lite is available on a small number of Android devices.